# Counting neighboring cells for Cellular Automata

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, conways-game-of-life

I wrote a quick JS implementation of Conway's.

In order to count the number of "live" cells that neighbour a given cell I manually check each of the 8 cells.

```
function getNeighbourCount(x, y){
    var intCount = 0;
    intCount = (getCell(x-1, y-1)? intCount+1 : intCount); //x-1, y-1
    intCount = (getCell(x, y-1)? intCount+1 : intCount);//x, y-1
    intCount = (getCell(x + 1, y-1)? intCount+1 : intCount);//x + 1, y-1
    intCount = (getCell(x-1, y)? intCount+1 : intCount);//x-1, y
    intCount = (getCell(x+1, y)? intCount+1 : intCount);//x+1, y
    intCount = (getCell(x-1, y+1)? intCount+1 : intCount);//x-1, y+1
    intCount = (getCell(x, y+1)? intCount+1 : intCount);//x, y+1
    intCount = (getCell(x+1, y+1)? intCount+1 : intCount);//x-1, y+1

    return intCount;
}
```

It works but seems clunky. Is there another more elegant technique to achieve the same thing? Preferably a technique that is adaptable for different kernel sizes.

Here's a fiddle with a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/3vpz14v7/

Notes:

- The state of the game is held in a 2D boolean array (50*50 in this example)
- getCell(x,y) returns the value of a cell with coords wrapped.

Comment: What you currently have is actually an optimization technique called loop unrolling.  You could implement this using two nested for loops, but when it executes you would have the same cost as for all these statements, plus the cost of the looping code.  With this approach you avoid the cost of the looping code.  Of course as you pointed out, this only works for a checking the nearest neighbors and if you want to check for any other distance it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the kernel in a more compact and visual format, like, say,

```
var kernel = [
  "111",
  "101",
  "111"]
```

You'd then write a function to decode that into calls to getCell, making your kernels easy to read and modify ("1" means "increment by 1 if the cell at that position was alive").

Answer (score 0):

Make this into a loop, then pack the loop into a summation statement.  Use the above kernel mask.  Store the cell states as True = alive, False = dead.  Then you can run a quick loop over the kernel mask and the chosen cell to generate the neighbor counts.  The following code shows an example for a cell matrix 4x4 (but only doing the middle cells, so as not to run off the edge).

```
cell = [[False, False, False, True],
        [False, True, True, False],
        [False, False, True, False],
        [True, True, False, True]]

count_mask = [[True, True, True],
              [True, False, True],
              [True, True, True]]

cellx = len(cell)
celly = len(cell[0])
kernelx = len(count_mask)
kernely = len(count_mask[0])

for x in range(1, cellx-1):
    for y in range(1, celly-1):
        live_count = sum([1 if cell[x+row-1][y+col-1] and count_mask[row][col] \
            else 0 for row in range(kernelx) for col in range(kernely)])

        print live_count
```

The resulting output is

```
2
3
5
4
```

Of course, you can capture this in a new matrix if you wish.
You can also be more Pythonic by putting that summation loop into a **reduce** call; I left it this way, since it's more accessible to most programmers.

Is this enough to move you forward?